# Managing dependencies with static libraries and apps

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm building an app which will consume a custom web API.  I want to create an objective-c adapter for this API separately from the app.  I'm thinking of doing this as a static library.

So for example MyAppAPI will be a static library and MyApp will link with this library.

MyAppAPI needs AFNetworking to access the web API.  But MyApp also needs AFNetworking for other reasons.

I want to be able to test MyAppAPI standalone with unit tests.  In order to test it, the static library project needs AFNetworking.  But I don't want AFNetworking to be compiled with MyAppAPI, I want that to be an external dependency.

So in fact both MyAppAPI and MyApp depend on AFNetworking and I want to be able to test MyAppAPI independently.

What's the best way to approach this kind of situation?  I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CocoaPods. They take care of dependency management for XCode projects and have a central repository (including AFNetworking).

On http://cocoapods.org you can find all information to get started.

Comment: I evaluated CocoaPods for this purpose, but it turns out to only be useful for completed dependencies.
When developing multiple projects in tandem, one needs the flexibility to build the top-level parent with a unique set of dependencies; while still being able to compile the child projects for the purpose of unit-testing. I've not found a solution yet, but it's clear this is a common use case.  Maybe identifying and removing duplicate symbols at linker stage is the easier way to go.